# In an if statement in javascript what is the difference between == and ===?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, conditional-statements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript === vs == : Does it matter which “equal” operator I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

In some JavaScript `if` statements I've seen the use of `===` as opposed to the standard `==`.

What is the difference between these? and should I be using either one of them over the other?

e.g.

```
if (variable == 'string') {
 return;
}
```

compared to:

```
if (variable === 'string') {
 return;
}
```

Comment: The "===" operator doesn't imply automatic conversion.

Comment: why does anyone want to downvote this question? often people face this in early stages of js learning.

Comment: thanks, now that i've seen the duplicate question I understand the difference. I tried searching the site before posting the question, for '==' and '===', but nothing came up.

Comment: why do people keep down voting this question? you try searching for === in the search box at the top of this site and see what comes up.

Comment: Can I suggest buying a copy of this: http://www.amazon.co.uk/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1337476385&sr=8-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `===` is a strict comparison (also checks type), whereas the `==` does a more relaxed comparison.

For instance:

```
var a = 'test';
if (a == true) {
   // this will be true
}

if ( a === true) {
   // this will not be true
}
```

Another example:

```
var b = '0';
if ( b == 0){
    // this will be true
}

if ( b === 0 ){
    // this will not be true
}
```

In particular it is very important when comparing *falsy* values. In Javascript all the following will be treated as false with relaxed comparison:

```
* false
* null
* undefined
* empty string ''
* number 0
* NaN
```

Comment: Strict being, matching the value and type, rather than just value :-) For example, '136' == 136 would return true, but '136' === 136 wouldn't

Comment: Good explanation thanks, the documentation on this site http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#types.equality is very useful too.

Answer (score 8):

=== also checks to be equal by type

For instance `1=="1"` is true but `1==="1"` is false